# IBM AS400 File not Found error while the Table Object is still there

Tags: python-3.x, database, db2, odbc

I'm relatively new to working with remote IBM databases. I am connecting to a remote IBM AS400 database using an ODBC Python3 connector in an Anaconda virtual environment on Windows 10. My connection that successfully works is:

```
import pyodbc

connection = pyodbc.connect(
    Driver='{iSeries Access ODBC Driver}',
    System='<host>',
    database='<database>',
    uid='<username>',
    pwd='<password>')
c1 = connection.cursor()
print('Connection established')
```

After connecting I run this command to see the list of tables:

```
c1.execute("select table_name from sysibm.sqltables")
```

And I see all the tables that I would need to query. But then when I try to query the contents of a specific table using:

```
c1.execute("select * from <database>.<table> LIMIT 100")
```

I get an error:

```
ProgrammingError: ('42S02', '[42S02] [IBM][System i Access ODBC Driver][DB2 for i5/OS]SQL0204 - <table> der Art *FILE in <database> nicht gefunden. (-204) (SQLExecDirectW)')
```

(It's in German, it means table of type *FILE in database not found)
(And I'm not using angle brackets, it's just for demonstration)

But a software like **DBeaver** returns valid data for both of them, for the tables list query and the specific table query. It's only python that gives the error.

Can anyone point out what could I be doing wrong? Or what can I run to pinpoint the problem?

Comment: Please select from `qsys2.tables` instead of `sysibm.sqltables` because the former checks the authid has access rights before returning a row, while the latter does not.   The i access driver also provides a tracing facility (refer to the documentation) that you can use at your client side to see what is really happening under the covers, although you need a certain competence to interpret the output.

Answer (score 0):

`<database>.<table>` is not correct.

On Db2 you have
database
-schema
--table

you should be using `<schema>.<table>` as the database has been specified in the connection string.

`<database>.<schema>.<table>` is supported when connecting to a remote database from the "local" one...but only for basic selects.  Db2 for IBM i doesn't support for example joining between a "local" and remote table.